# MapView showing unmatched data on annotatioin?

Tags: xcode, ios4, mkmapview

I am new to iPhone programming and i was practicing MKMapView.But it is showing unappropriated data.
I have two ViewControllers. On the first ViewController , We have a button with this below written coding :-
  There are two array having the data shown below:-
  **DetailArray:-**
 inNetwork = true;

```
    resName = taverna1;  
    statusColor = "#FF0000";
    statusString = "30 MIN";
    true = hasPromo;
},
    {
    false = hasPromo;
    inNetwork = true;
    resName = bungalow;
    statusColor = 00FF00;
    statusString = "NO WAIT";
},
    {
    inNetwork = true;
    resName = "casa_nostra";
    statusColor = 00FF00;
    statusString = "NO WAIT";
    true = hasPromo;
},
    {
    inNetwork = true;
    resName = karebu;
    statusColor = 00FF00;
    statusString = "NO WAIT";
    true = hasPromo;
}




**Annotation Array**

(
    "<MyAnnotViewController: 0x8457b60>",
    "<MyAnnotViewController: 0x845a040>",
    "<MyAnnotViewController: 0x84439f0>",
    "<MyAnnotViewController: 0x806f090>"
)
```

MyAnnoationViewcontroller is subclass of MKAnnotation.It contains title  and coordinates successfully.

```
  SecondViewController *_SecondViewController =[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    _SecondViewController.DetailArray = detailArray;
    _SecondViewController.annotationArray = annotationArray;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:_SecondViewController animated:YES];
```

On the secondViewController:-

```
MKMapView * MapView =[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)];
MapView.delegate =self;
MapView.showsUserLocation =NO;

[MapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];

[self.view addSubview:MapView];
```

on the Delegate method it's showing very uncertain result on the annotations.Chlorinates and title is desired output. But color of first rest name is showing the color of second restaurant and second is showing any other color. Please anybody help me to get out of this problem. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your code for `viewForAnnotation` so I'm just going to take a stab in the dark and guess you are setting the colour of the view you are drawing based on the order of your array and not on the annotation object that is passed in to `viewForAnnotation`. You can find lots of questions about `viewForAnnotation` here on StackOverflow.

P.S. Are you really using iOS 4.0? That's pretty old.